# Getting not valid cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element Employee. No child element is expected at this point

Tags: web-services, xsd

I am using webservices.Using the below xml code.I am getting the error which is below while running the code.

> Not validcvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'EmployeeAllergy'. No child element is expected at this point.

Here's the code:

```
<EmployeeAllergy>
        <allergyID>1020</allergyID>
        <allergyTypeID>FDB</allergyTypeID>
        <allergySeverityTypeID>Mild</allergySeverityTypeID>
        <allergyComment>ssss</allergyComment>
        <onsetDate>20140317</onsetDate>
</EmployeeAllergy>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We'll need to see the XML schema that defines the web service, or a relevant fragment of it.

Comment: XML schema in the sense namespace right?

Comment: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
       <NCScript xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">

Comment: @user3041990 The XSD file you have for that XML.

Comment: @lexicore I didn't get u

Comment: @user3041990 Show us your schema. You have a validation problem, we need to see the schema (the XSD file) to say what's wrong. And you don't "run" XML as code.